# Elisp: function to paste heading lines in an Org-mode buffer

Tags: org-mode, insert

I would like to have a function that pastes a certain heading:

```
"#+TITLE:\n#+STARTUP: overview"
```

I tried using `insert-buffer-substring`:

```
(insert-buffer-substring "#+TITLE:\n#+STARTUP: overview")
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Try  the function `insert`.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NickD suggested in a comment, you can use function `insert`.

```lisp
(insert "#+TITLE:\n#+STARTUP: overview")
```

`C-h f insert-buffer-substring` tells you that you need to pass it a buffer as argument.  And the rest of what it tells you makes clear that it doesn't at all do what you're looking for.

`C-h f insert` tells you:

> `insert` is a built-in function in `C source code`.
>
> `(insert &rest ARGS)`
>
> Insert the arguments, either strings or characters, at point.
> ...